# Replace quotes in a string with a HTML tag

Tags: php, string

I have the following string stored in a variable in PHP.

```
The words inside the quotes should be in '''bold'''. Like '''this''' and '''that'''
```

Here triple quotes `'''` are used to represent that the word should be shown bold.

What is the most efficient way to replace this with the `<strong>` tag?

Comment: One of the easiest would be to use str_replace("'''","<strong>",$string,1); And do this again for </strong>

Comment: @Tuim But I could have more than one word which needs to be bolded.

Comment: `preg_replace` will help you. I am not good at regular expressions !! :)

Comment: Then loop it but I think atrepp has a more appropriate answer.

Comment: @Tuim The 4th parameter in str_replace() is used to return the number of replacements, not the number of replacements to perform.

Comment: You could use preg_replace then which does support $limit.

Comment: It sounds like you're writing a quick markup library.  Please don't.  There are *lots* of existing ones out there that do the job very well.

Comment: @Charles No I am not create a markup library. This is the only substitution that I have to make.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i would say [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) with something like that :

`$new_string = preg_replace('/\'\'\'([^\']+)\'\'\'/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $string);`

Comment: the only problem with my solution your words must not have ' inside

Comment: Is it possible to modify the regex so that it collects all characters until 3 ''' are present, instead of one?

Comment: maybe if you replace all ''' by something else…

Comment: But the problem is identifying the character with which I can replace `'''` with. If that character is present in the word, then the same problem occurs again.

Comment: Why not just use a multiline dot with a lazy quantifier?

Answer (score 1):

Even though [@atrepp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1517028/atrepp)'s answer is correct, I ended up using the following function

```
function makeBold($string) {
    $quote = '&#39;&#39;&#39;';
    $count = substr_count($string, $quote);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $count/2; $i++) {
        $string = preg_replace("/$quote/", '<strong>', $string, 1);
        $string = preg_replace("/$quote/", '</strong>', $string, 1);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

because

- My string was actually in encoded form (ie) it had `&#39;` instead of `'`
- His answer doesn't work when the word to be bolded has `'` in it

Comment: nice solution, if you do that it is better to use str_replace with the count parameter `$string = str_replace($quote, '<strong>', $string, 1);`

Comment: @atrepp The count parameter in `str_replace()` is an input parameter which finds out how many substitution were made. It doesn't limit how may substitution should eb made.